# Trying to comment some lines from dovecot conf file

Tags: sed

I'm trying to comment this lines:

```
passdb {
  driver = pam
   [session=yes] [setcred=yes] [failure_show_msg=yes] [max_requests=<n>]
   [cache_key=<key>] [<service name>]
  args = dovecot
}
```

via sed:

```
sed -i '1!N; s/passdb {\
  driver = pam\
   \[session=yes\] \[setcred=yes\] \[failure_show_msg=yes\] \[max_requests=\<n\>\]\
   \[cache_key=\<key\>\] \[\<service name\>\]\
  args = dovecot\
}/#passdb {\
#  driver = pam\
#   [session=yes] [setcred=yes] [failure_show_msg=yes] [max_requests=<n>]\
#   [cache_key=<key>] [<service name>]\
#  args = dovecot\
#}/' t
```

But it doesn't match what I need, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is comment the lines between `passdb` and `}`, then the following should suffice

```
sed -i '/^passdb {/,/}/s/^/#/g' file
```

Comment: That was fast, amazingly fast, tnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/^passdb {/,/^}/ {$0="#"$0}1' file
```